# How do I prove that all people are illusion and only I am real in this world?

Tags: metaphysics, subjectivity, solipsism

I am sure that, I am the only real person who is living in this world and all you all just illusion.

My brain works in two ways it creates the world and makes me feel it i.e it only generates both input and output stimulus . Whatever I think in my brain,it will be created outside the world but in such a way I don't realize it.And even matter and energy can be created through my brain but I am not aware of it..

So nobody is real in this world except me.

Please note :to explain "I am like semi-god I can create anything and might be I am not aware of it "thats why this question arised ...it is nothing to do with dreams/matrix ..
So how do I make realize all of you that you are just a illusion and created by me?

Comment: I would say that you first should convince you that it is the truth and then the hard part is getting you to think that you want people ('illusions') to be aware of their condition. May seems really simple but I would assume that it would be quite difficult for a character to actually accepts that kind of extreme loneliness while the illusion of being with people can be so comfortable.

Comment: @Riff , "illusion of being with people can be so comfortable" is not comfortable . Now I am feeling even your comment is illusion which is just created by me . I am feeling so foolish that I am only posting the question and I am only creating the comments and answers in other names ...

Comment: @AmruthA Well either way it seems to be up to you only since your the only real thing in the world. If you imagine me being a blockhead not believing your *theory* then I'll be, if you **really** want me to acknowledge my being an illusion then I will.

Comment: @AmruthA And just so you know what to tell the doctors to get taken care of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solipsism_syndrome ^^

Comment: @AmruthA if I am not real why are you trying to convince me of _anything_? What do you even mean with your statement that I am not "real"? Even if am "only" a figment of your imagination, it means I am a real figment of your imagination, am I not?

Comment: you mean your subconscious can create material world?

Comment: So where does your brain come from?

Comment: @user6760 Yes it can create anything..

Comment: @Innovine It is like asking where did god come from ? there must be starting point and I am starting point of it i.e only I am created till now..

Comment: While not exactly the same question, I believe your question is answered in [Are there philosophers who examined the reasons for believing in the existence of other people?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/661/2953). If not, please clarify. Also related: [1](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/6979/2953); [2](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/206/2953); [3](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/70/2953).

Comment: You have already proven it, the only existing person knows it is true. Pat yourself on the back next time the illussionary people in white coats undo your illusory straight jacket (Y)

Comment: Funny thing about solipsism is that your solipsism is immediately refuted by anyone else and anyone else's solipsism is immediately refuted by you. Believe whatever works for you, but know the difference, eh?

Comment: This sounds like a *you* problem, my dude. Just control your imagination. How hard can it be? In fact, you should easily be able to generate a comment from me stating clearly that you are the only real thing. Make it happen!

Comment: @philosodad, see my brain dragged back to this question after 7 years....aahh i was cured...now got back the disease ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple answer is:

a) You can't

and

b) It doesn't matter if we are.

## I think, therefore I am.

Note that this statement doesn't include you, or him over there, it's a statement about *me*. Beyond that it doesn't matter whether it's all an illusion, a simulation, or the matrix. The simple fact is that this is who I am, whatever the "truth" behind it is, I am real because I believe I am.

For further details, you should probably head to the philosophy SE.

Comment: I had a dream once where I was walking along a forest path with a friend, and I suddenly became lucid (realised I was dreaming) and said to him: "haha, sorry mate, this is a dream, you don't really exist". And he replied "but... I think therefore I am!". he was convinced of it. I woke up in a panic.

Comment: @Innovine, I think that's something you need to resolve with your imaginary friend, especially if he only exists while you're dreaming ;)

Comment: @Separatrix Good luck with firing up that conversation again :D

Comment: @Innovine that fits into Separatrix's explanation though. "it doesn't matter whether it's all an illusion, a simulation, or the matrix." Your imaginary friend DID and arguably STILL DOES exist; even if he is just a figment of your imagination, that still means he IS ie. exists. And by now, he is also a figment of my imagination and of anyone else who reads your message.

Answer (score 3):

You will know it is an illusion if you are starving/dehydrated to the point of being near death despite eating and drinking normally.  Hopefully when your body reaches that state your brain will no longer able to keep up with the illusions and so you will be able to confirm what you expect.

The premise is that since you are the only real person around, and you go to the local fast food place, get a chicken sandwich, and eat it, what actually happen?  Well if you were the only one, then who prepared the sandwich you think you are eating?  Odds are your mind is tricking you into thinking there is a sandwich there and everything is okay and fine, when really your eating air and your body is slowly dying from neglect.

Note this strategy will not work if you are in your own coma/dream world and there are people outside of it that are actively keeping your body alive.  You can attempt to test this case by not eating or drinking and see if you experience anything in line with being thirsty or hungry, if not then congrats you proved it.  However the illusionary world might also simulate these things to the point where you still die.  Needless to say this would be a bad strategy since, odds are you are actually in reality and if you die while trying to prove it, kind of defeats the whole point.

Comment: Actually there is nothing deal with starving/death thing , to explain "I am like semi-god I can create anything and might be I am not aware of it "thats why this question arised ...it is nothing to do with dreams/matrix  ..

Answer (score 2):

> So how do I make realize all of you that you are just a illusion and created by me?

See, if your brain shapes the world accordingly to your beliefs, and you believe other people are mere illusions, everything you assume about these illusions would come true. So, the solution is to start believing that all people should accept you as their creator.

If it does not work, and people would still refuse to call you their overlord - probably, one of your initial assumptions was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

**Clashing known things with unknown.**

Since the statement says, the brain creates the stimulus describing the world, it will be able to describe only, what it already knows, or capable to make up from fractions. It can be challenged. And if discrepancy is catched, it can be a base of proving, the experience is an illusion.

Everything we sort as fantasy in current time literature, is an imagination. If an imagination can be identified, it is a proof for illusion. 
Or for the sci-fi **Blade Runner** employs a questionnaire, which serves as tool to decide whether the questionned person is a clone or <s>real</s> original person.

**Samples of indeterminated occourances**

Topics, which would qualify in real world as active research field in science, but do not have results yet, outcomes are not trivial. A brain, which has not collected result of a research may create different outcomes on different parameters, or even on (thought to be) the same.

At some point, people on Earth supposedly realized that the Sun is not following the very same track day-to-day, but is has a slight change as it progresses in time for seasons. It can be called belief, but thinking that all days are the same is an illusion.

A fun example for people would be the mask joke for Prince John in [Robin Hood: Men in Tights (1993)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107977/). He had a wart on his head, but always placed to a different spot in every scene. Description said, he has a wart, but no detail on exactly where. Warts do not tend to change place, and due to lack of information, several makeshift instances can be generated.

**Preconcepts**

A brain is attempting to apply patterns. If a single brain is generating illusions, they will always be plausible, straight-forward, doubtless. There will be no suprises, everything will follow on a calculatable direction (I do not mean necessary calm, but predictible). If you never meet anything, that you would mark as suprise, "never would have thought about that", it is a good sign to begin coming up with second thoughts.