# How common is solipsism among philosophers, scientists and common people?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, solipsism

How common is solipsism? On the opinion of philosophers what percentage of the population believes in solipsism? 1. How many percent of philosophers believe in solipsism? 2. How many percent of scientists believe in solipsism? 3. How many percent of the population believes in solipsism?
What philosopher's meaning about this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does modern philosophy believe in solipsism?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/78482/does-modern-philosophy-believe-in-solipsism)

Comment: Most common people do not know what that is, and philosophers and scientists despise it. Nobody bothered to conduct polls, if they were conducted it would barely register.